# Suddenly QTP stops recognizing Active x in between

Tags: qtp, activexobject

While running a script with Active x add-ins loaded, QTP is able to recognize and act on Active X controls But suddenly after running the script for sometime the hook with Active X control is no more exists. It starts recognizing Active x control as Win Object.

This problem is:

1)On Stand alone window based application.

2)seen on Debug build not on End user Application

3)both on QTP 11 and QTP 12

Particular Doubts:

1)If End user and Debug build of application is to be suspected then in what lines?

2)What can make the Active X hook lost with QTP ?

As it is difficult to repeat this in between the script I require a solution.

If any one knows any Input, Please provide me.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening only for specific dialog or entire application?If it is only for specific dialog use IF condition to solve the problem.It is just a workaround